# Using condition operator ? for getting even number

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a simple code, which will take a input from user and save it into number variable and then I am trying to find out if this number is even, or odd using condition operator, but I am bit stuck of how to use Console.WriteLine() in this condition operator and where to call it. Maybe someone can help me to understand it more clearly. Thanks in advance!

```
using System;

namespace ConditionalOperatorExercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number;
            number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            var evenNumber = number % number == 1 ? Console.WriteLine("Number is even"); : Console.WriteLine("Number is odd");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to write `number % 2` to check the `number` is even or odd. If it return `0`, then it's even, if not, then it's odd. Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-

Comment: When you use a ternal condition ```"bool ? :"```, you can't return a void fonction like Console.Writeline() you need to return a value. 

If you want to show with condition, you need to use a ```if()``` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this:

```
var message = number % 2 == 0 ? "Number is even" : "Number is odd";
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Please note that you need to check the `number % 2` is equal to `0` instead, to check whether a number is even or odd.